# Airflow 2 : get execution date inside task

Tags: python, airflow

I used to create tasks with the python operator and retrieve execution in airflow 1 as follow

```
def task(**kwargs):
    date = kwargs['execution_date']
```

What is the correct way to do it with the new taskflow api ? (probably missed it)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the execution context with `get_current_context` method:

```py
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

@task
def my_task():
    context = get_current_context()
    ti = context["ti"]
    date = context["execution_date"]
```

Docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#accessing-context-variables-in-decorated-tasks). Try it out!

#### Update:

The code above works just fine **but**, the so called `context` objects, are directly accesible in task-decorated functions. This means that there is no need to import `get_current_context` anymore. The context objects are accesible just by declaring the parameterss in the task signature:

```py
@task
def my_task(ds=None, ti=None):
    print(f"execution_date:{ds}")
    print(f"task_instance:{ti}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know how I missed it ! Works like a charm

Comment: Glad to heard that!

Comment: The documentation link does not point to the right page anymore, maybe this is the new one: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html#accessing-context-variables-in-decorated-tasks

Comment: The variables mentioned here seem to be deprecated; there is an updated list unter https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html